# What does 'angular' mean?

Tags: terminology

I  quote uses of 'angular' and 'angularity' in [*The Rough Guide to Classical Music* (2010 5 ed)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1848364768).

### Some uses of 'angular'

p. 286 Bottom, Right Column

> Korngold’s *Symphony* (1952) is the most uncompromisingly modern of all his works, more
>   **angular** than his earlier compositions, yet no less
>   enjoyable.

p. 379 Bottom, Right Column

> #### Symphony No. 4 –
>
> The Inextinguishable
>   The idea of the life force is at the heart of the third
>   symphony and the same is true for Symphony
>   No. 4 – The Inextinguishable (1914–16). Its title
>   was explained by the composer as an attempt “…
>   to indicate in one word what only music has the
>   power to express in full: the elemental Will of
>   Life. Music is Life and, like it, inextinguishable.”
>   Written when Nielsen’s marriage was floundering and shortly after his resignation from the
>   Copenhagen Opera, this symphony abounds in
>   conflict and contradiction. Its opening is frenetic,
>   with percussion, strings and wind seeming to vie
>   with each other in clamorous discourse before
>   giving way to an ardent, affirmative melody in
>   the clarinets. The brief second movement suggests the carefree sounds of a village wind band,
>   but the slow movement – with its **angular** string
>   lines – is unremittingly bleak. The finale culminates in a musical battle between two sets of
>   spatially separated timpani, a battle that is only

p. 380

> resolved by the recall of the lyrical melody from
>   the first movement.

p. 492 Middle, Left Column

> #### St Luke’s Passion
>
> Scored for huge forces – three solo voices, narrator, three mixed choirs, boys’ choir and
>   orchestra – the *St Luke’s Passion* was Penderecki’s
>   most ambitious concert work up to the time of
>   its composition (1962–66). Following on from
>   the extreme expressionism of the early 1960s,
>   the *Passion* marks a synthesis of avant-garde
>   techniques with the great traditions of Western
>   choral music – in particular the works of Bach,
>   Palestrina and Gregorian chant. Commissioned
>   to commemorate the 700th anniversary of
>   Münster Cathedral, the work employs **angular**
>   dissonances and some unconventional but
>   dramatic effects (such as crowd noises), but communicates a genuinely devotional mood and tells
>   its story with undeniable authority and intensity

p. 594 Middle, Left Column.

> #### Amériques & Ionisation
>
> Varèse’s search for new sonic possibilities was influenced by Luigi Russolo, the Italian Futurist who
>   created noise machines and whose manifesto The
>   Art of Noises proposed a new world of organized
>   sound which simulated the disparate soundscape
>   of modern urban life. In *Amériques*, premiered
>   by members of the Philadelphia Orchestra under
>   Stokowski, Varèse calls for nine percussionists
>   including two sets of timpani, a siren and the roar
>   of a lion (later changed to Ondes Martenot). It’s a
>   work of raw rhythmic energy – with the occasional
>   moment of lyrical repose – which evokes the brash,
>   **angular** and violent sounds of the city. Varèse
>   described it as being about “new worlds on earth,
>   in the sky or in the minds of men” and it marks
>   the beginning of his fascination with the expressive
>   possibilities of percussion.

### Uses of 'angularity'

p. 146 Middle, Right Column

> #### Piano Music
>
> As well as being a fine pianist, Copland the
>   composer used the piano to work out his ideas:
>   it’s not surprising, therefore, that throughout
>   his career he wrote several pieces for the instrument which though not as well-known as his
>   orchestral pieces are among his most challenging and original compositions. Both the
>   *Piano Variations* (1931) and the *Piano Sonata*
>   (1941) are uncompromisingly modernist works
>   which owe something to both Prokofiev and
>   Bartók in their percussiveness and **angularity**
>   but which are also shot through with Copland’s
>   characteristic “Americanisms” – sparse textures, widely spaced intervals, jazz-inspired
>   rhythms. The *Sonata* is more epic in scope.
>   Copland referred to it as grandiose, albeit “… a
>   very dry and bare grandiosity, instead of the fat
>   grandiosity of a big orchestral work …” There
>   is also a definite sense of wartime anxiety in its
>   restlessness, ominous hints of tolling bells and
>   generally elegaic undertow.

p. 381 Bottom, Left Column.

> #### Wind Concertos
>
> After Nielsen had composed his *Wind Quintet*
>   in 1922, he decided to write a concerto for each
>   of the players who had first performed it. In the
>   end, he completed only two before he died, but
>   both are impressive compositions. The *Flute
>   Concerto* is a predominantly high-spirited and
>   lyrical work, and there is some highly beautiful
>   writing within its single-movement structure.
>   The *Clarinet Concerto* is in a different vein, with
>   Nielsen embracing – or parodying – the unsentimental **angularity** of modernists like Stravinsky. It
>   can be a little hard work in the hands of the wrong
>   performers, but it is undoubtedly an exciting and
>   unusual work.

Comment: All of this type of "writing about music is" smoke and mirrors. It means whatever they writer thought it meant. Possibly, putting together all your quotes it just means the writer doesn't like "modern music" very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem fairly apparent from the context of some of the other words surrounding 'angular' et al, that it refers to dissonant musical phrases, and musical lines with larger jumps than is normal, rather than the smoother lines more often encountered in the more lyrical styles of music that are often more listenable. Instead of being gently soothed by such music, the author intimates that the listener will be pushed violently around sonically.

Answer (score 3):

You can describe music as being angular when the line is not smooth and flowing, probably employing intervallic leaps.  It can suggest a texture that is lean rather than full.

Answer (score 0):

'Angular' is being used here as an antonym of 'smooth', 'melodic'.